# Jquery DOM Manipulation Advanced Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am working with some sort of E-Shop Template and I can only manipulate some stuff with Jquery and JS.

**Problem No 1:**

I want to give the first box with the Content "Hello and Welcome!" and  some background-Image. Problem is, that this box has some padding and I need to set the Background to the parent "inner-Wrapper" of this Div.

Is there a way to select the first "inner-wrapper" and check if the Content is "hello and welcome!" in the Content-box?

---

**Problem No 2:**

Box 1 - Box 4 Need another Background-Image.

I know some basic Jquery stuff but I struggle with those advanced stuff. And after 4 hours of trial and error I have to ask you guys.

I hope you can help me, and thanks in advance!

```html
<div class="row">

    <div class="inner-wrapper">
            <div class="content-box">

                Hello and Welcome!

            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
            <div class="content-box">

                <img src="" alt="">

            </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="content-box">

            Box 1

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="content-box">

            Box 2

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="content-box">

            Box 3

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="content-box">

            Box 4

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: _"Problem No2"_ --- Try and keep to one problem per question.

Comment: Problem n°1 : `$('.inner-wrapper').first().find('.content-box').text() === "Hello and Welcome!"`

Comment: *Problem 1* `$( ".inner-wrapper:contains('Hello and Welcome!')" )eq(0)` solved using `.contains()`  *Problem 2*  => `$( ".inner-wrapper:contains('Box 1')" ).eq(0).css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking the text you can add an extra class and check for that class Or you can give a seperate background image for the   `$('.content-box')`   inside the first `.inner-wrapper`

```js
$(function(){
  $('.content-box').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('firstBox')){
     
        $(this).parent().css('background-image', 'url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150)');
    }else{
     $(this).parent().css('background-image', 'url(http://via.placeholder.com/150x150)');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.inner-wrapper{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-size: cover;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">

    <div class="inner-wrapper">
            <div class="content-box firstBox">

                Hello and Welcome!

            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
            <div class="content-box">

                <img src="" alt="">

            </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="content-box">

            Box 1

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="content-box">

            Box 2

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="content-box">

            Box 3

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="content-box">

            Box 4

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```